# Is the purpose of a "UI" font like Roboto & Helvetica to be as invisible as possible?

Tags: interface, font, social

In selecting UI fonts, it seems that fonts with the most readability, and the least "character" are always picked.

Such a font allows the main content relating to the goals of the interface, be it pictures, conversations, or conversations, to stand out. These fonts, usually used in buttons or admin info (dates, user time posted), serve their core purpose before quickly fading away from the user's attention.

When we want to check for a photo album, for example, our eyes quickly search for the name of an album and once we find it, we move on to the album content, not remembering the font that easily enabled the quick search of an album name.

What really is the consideration, if not, when picking such a font for a website or application?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, the word most people to use to describe text is **Readability**.

> **Readability** is the ease with which a written text can be understood by a reader.

If a text is easy to read and comprehend it allows a user to spend less time reading it. It also allows the user to incur less cognitive load because it takes less thinking to process the text.

So yes, in a sense, some text is designed to have less of a footprint in the users mental model. But I wouldn't say they're intended to be *invisible* in the visual sense.